# Plot an apparently flat function

Tags: plotting

I would like to plot

```
     E^(x^2 + 7 x - 30) - 1
```

near 0

```
 Plot[E^(x^2 + 7 x - 30) - 1, {x, -5, 0}]
```

works but I could not see anay thing near the minimum -- 7/2 --- because  the rounding effect make the function flat. How could I obtain a nice graph. Of course I have tried to set PlotRange without any success.

Comment: The `E^(-30)` is a huge problem since it's such a small number. Why not plot the following version of the function instead? It is merely a shift and then a stretch, but you can always add those old numbers in: `Plot[Evaluate[(f[x] + 1)/Exp[-30]], {x, -5, 0}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.0002}]`.

Comment: points = Table[{x, N[E^(x^2+7x-30)-1, 64]}, {x,-5,0,1/10}];
ListPlot[points, PlotRange -> {-1 - 11/10*10^-13, -1 + 10^-13},
Ticks -> {{-5,-4,-3,-2,-1}, {N[-1-10^-13,20], -1, N[-1+10^-13,20]}},
 AxesOrigin -> {0,-1-11/10*10^-13}, Joined->True] and if you study that carefully then you might be able to use this to zoom in even further to try to see your minimum

Comment: After reading all thos solutions I was doubtfull since no one show that there is trully a minimum then by mistake i fell on this very weird result: thisPlot[Evaluate[E^(x^2 + 7*x - 30)/Exp[-30]], {x, -4, -3}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 0.0000005}] gives nothing but Plot[Evaluate[E^(x^2 + 7*x - 30)/Exp[-30]], {x, -4, -3}, 
 PlotRange -> {, 0.0000005}] is great --- of course Ma complains but it dos the job. WHY ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LogPlot[E^(x^2 + 7 x - 30), {x, -5, 0}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {-5, 10^-20},
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "f[x]+1"}]
```

[image]

beware this doesn't work well due to numerical precision issues:

```
 f[x_] = E^(x^2 + 7 x - 30) - 1
 LogPlot[ f[x] + 1, ... ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm making a fool of my self but

```
E^(x^2 + 7 x - 30) - 1 == -1 + E^(-30 + 7*x + x^2)
```

> `True`

```
Plot[-1 + E^(-30 + 7*x + x^2), {x, -10, 2.8}]
```

[image]

And take Alpha into consideration:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find the minimum of

```
f[x_] := E^(x^2 + 7 x - 30) - 1
```

By adding one, this has a min at the same location as

```
f2[x_] := E^(x^2 + 7 x - 30)
```

By taking the log of both sides, this has a min at the same location as

```
f3[x_] := x^2 + 7 x - 30
```

This can be handled by

```
FindMinimum[f3[x], x]

x -> -3.5
```

which shows that the min of your function occurs at -3.5. Evaluating f[-3.5] gives -1, which is indeed the minimum value that f can attain.