# Plot a flat function (2)

Tags: plotting

(In fact  I realize threre are two questiona inside this one)

This is an uncredible sequel of the question [Plot an apparently flat function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127574/plot-an-apparently-flat-function).

After a lot of effort and suggestion

```
 Plot[Evaluate[E^(x^2 + 7*x - 30)/Exp[-30]], {x, -4, -3}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 0.0000005}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", 
   "(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(4\)]\)[x]-1)/Exp[-30]]"}]
```

This gives nothing - there is truly a minimum in the function - and this

```
Plot[Evaluate[E^(x^2 + 7*x - 30)/Exp[-30]], {x, -4, -3}, 
 PlotRange -> {, 0.0000005}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", 
  "(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(4\)]\)[x]-1)/Exp[-30]]"}]
```

works perfectly even if MA complains.

So now how insert this local comportment as a zooming inside a large figure ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for manual setting of the range:

```
Plot[Evaluate[E^(x^2 + 7*x - 30)/Exp[-30]], {x, -4, -3}, 
  PlotRange -> {All, Full}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", 
    "(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(4\)]\)[x]-1)/Exp[-30]]"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should give PlotRange in its full form:

```
Plot[Evaluate[E^(x^2+7*x-30)/Exp[-30]],{x,-4,-3},PlotRange->{{-4,-3},{4.5*10^-6,6.5*10^-6}},AxesLabel->{"x","(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(4\)]\)[x]-1)/Exp[-30]]"}]
```

[image]